# Using Divine Smite as a dual-wielder

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, paladin, divine, bonus-action

*Divine Smite* allows my Paladin to expend a spell slot to deal extra damage after landing a melee attack. My character wields two swords. Since *Divine Smite* isn't a bonus action (because the rules don't say it is), I can use my bonus action to attack with my second sword while also using *Divine Smite*. So, providing both attacks land and I have two spell slots to use, can I use *Divine Smite* twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, you can divine smite on any hit

The only limitation on how many times you can divine smite is your spell slots. But do note that with wielding two weapons, any bonus action smite casting will not be open to you unless you forgo an attack at some point to get it going.

Comment: Neat. I assume by 'any bonus action smite casting' you mean casting spells like _Thunderous Smite_?

Comment: @jonnybolton16 Correct. All of the Smite spells are bonus action casts.